# FFmpeg on Xcode

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, streaming, live

I'm developing an app for ios which uses IP Camera to stream live videos to the user. I installed macports and ffmpeg using terminal on my mac. I have taken the IP Camera output and converted into .ts file using ffmpeg on terminal. Now I want the procedure to do the same using Xcode i.e. writing code in xcode to convert IP Camera output to .ts files.
                                           Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this app do, why converting it to a ts file rather than just streaming it from the camera to the device,doesn't your ip camera support live rtsp feeds, if you have some requirement that does require the conversion it might be faster to do it on an external server than on the device, if you must do it on the device there are a few api's that might help with the conversion like live555, but I would just stream it.

Comment: I'm converting the stream for using HTTP Live Streaming tools as recommended by Apple for ios devices. I want the app to to be published on appstore. So I wanted the procedure of ffmpeg in xcode.

Comment: a lot of my clients use rtsp for ipcam streaming and we've never had an issue with approval from apple. seems they treat live and static content differently since HLS has a big show stopper , ie. up to 30 second latency